# python 2.7.2 install

Tags: python, installation

I tried to install `Python 2.7.2` from source.

I run ./configure, make and make install.
It complains the following errors when make install.
`from _struct import *
ImportError: No module named _struct`

My OS is: centOS 5.2 final
GCC version: 4.1.2

Comment: try `make distclean
./configure
make
make install`

Comment: I tried. Still the same error.

Comment: ok, discussion regarding problem [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue9631)

Comment: added link as an answer. upvote and accept if the problem is solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem in Centos. The solutions in the link given by Fredrik can't resolve my problem.

My workaround is to install python2.6 using RPM package. The method can be found here:

[Install python 2.6 in CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465036/install-python-2-6-in-centos)
 : "use the EPEL-repository, and then do sudo yum install python26 to install python 2.6"