# Python 2.7.2 installation difficulties

Tags: python, linux, compiler-errors, redhat

I am trying to install `Python 2.7.2`  from source files in my `Linux` machine. But I am running into the following problem which has been discussed [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649678/python-2-7-2-install).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/a/b/python2.7.2/linux26_x86_64/lib/python2.7/compileall.py", line 16, in <module>
    import struct
  File "/a/b/python3.7.2/linux26_x86_64/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: No module named _struct
gmake: *** [libinstall] Error 1
```

I followed the [link](http://bugs.python.org/issue9631) provided in the answer and tried a suggestion by Hans Lellelid (hozn) to modify `site.py` but still no luck.

My system details are:

```
% cat /etc/*-release
CentOS release 4.6 (Final)

% uname -av
Linux scdbuild04 2.6.9-67.ELsmp #1 SMP Fri Nov 16 12:49:06 EST 2007 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

% gcc -v
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-checking --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-java-awt=gtk --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-9)
```

Comment: do you have to use such an old version of CentOS? It would be much easier on a contemporary distro

Comment: @tMC this is at work. I am unfortunately stuck with this.

Comment: Are their any build errors pertaining to the building of _struct?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a lot safer if you just installed this into a virtualenv instead?

Comment: I ran into the same problem and had success w/ this guide: http://villaroad.com/2010/10/rolling-python-2-6-2-on-centos-5-3/

Comment: @pyInTheSky I am not a `su` (root) and thus can't use rpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Activestate Python](http://www.activestate.com/activepython) for installing Python 2.7. I also ran into a problem in the installation which was solved by setting `PYTHONHOME` env variable correctly as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6505383/476388).

```
% setenv PYTHONHOME /a/b/python2.7.2/linux26_x86_64
% tar -xzf ActivePython-2.7.2.5-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
% cd ActivePython-2.7.2.5-linux-x86_64
% ./install.sh -I /a/b/python2.7.2/linux26_x86_64
```