# Install python2.6 on centos7.4

Tags: python, centos, ambari

I am a beginner at ambari following below url to build. 
**https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.6.1**

I find that it needs python2.6, but the version of yum source is above 2.7. How can I install python2.6 on centos7.4?

I have tried epel source but no help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to run it against 2.7?

Comment: Of course, ambari needs python2.6 to build, maybe you can have a look on above url.

Comment: I did. Did you try reading further?

Comment: Maybe this url can explain this:https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Ambari+Development

Comment: I read that. Apparently you got stuck on the line that says "Python 2.6".

Comment: It does not say any version above python2.6 which i think it needs pyhton2.6

Comment: Except for all the other parts that talk about 2.7, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sudo yum install python26
```

or

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install python26
```

or see this [stackover post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465036/install-python-2-6-in-centos)

Comment: After install, the python is 2.7

Comment: python-wheel==2.6 can not be found in yum source.

Comment: python==2.6 also can not be found

Comment: still not found in epel source

Comment: have you seen that stack overflow post which link is provided in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad question since i just want to build ambari-2.6.1.

On my side, i make a soft link '/usr/bin/python2.6' to '/usr/bin/python2.7', then everything works.

But after try to use, it failed. It seems that soft link can not work as expected.